# How to get the latest value from selected drop down

Tags: reactjs

i have this dropdonw that populates dynamically. when the user selects an item it should set the

state `'selectedValue'` with the `'SelectedValue'`. i have written the folllowng code but when i ran this code the `alert()` always display the old value not the newly selected value. why is that?

the function in react class is this

```
ddlProdCatsChanegeEvent: function(e) {

  

   if (this.state.isMounted)

   {

       var ele = document.getElementById('ddlCategories');

       var seleValue = ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text;

       this.setState({selectedValue:seleValue});

       alert(this.state.selectedValue);//this always display the old selected value NOT THE new one

   }

},
```

the state is this:

```
getInitialState:function(){

   return{data1:[], data2:[], isMounted:false, selectedValue:''}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** of all I will recommend you to make use of `refs` to access the dom element instead of plain javascript. Not that its necessary but because its JSX syntax and you can use it.

**Secondly**, setState takes some time to mutate the state and thats the reason you are seeing the previouly selected value because it has not been changed before the alert is being triggered.

Put the alert box in the setState callback method as

```
this.setState({selectedValue: value}, function(){
        alert(this.state.selectedValue);
      });
```

Complete code.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {

   return{ selectedValue:''}
   },
   handleChange: function(e) {

        var value = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.selectValue).value;
      this.setState({selectedValue: value}, function(){
        alert(this.state.selectedValue);
      });

    },
  render: function() {

    return (<div>
          Hello {this.props.name}
          <div>
          <select ref="selectValue" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>
          </div>
          </div>
  )}
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/56236/)**

Comment: You saved my day thanks. One more thing is there a way to find out the differences between version .13 and .15 of reactjs

Comment: Go through the documentation of React 15. It lists the changes made https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html.

Comment: @Shbham thanks for the answer is have marked it as answered but I cannot give point cus I'm not allowed  :(

Comment: @vitofila Happy to Help :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Take a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/56238/)

React highly discourages manipulating DOM directly, or using methods like `getElementById()`. So writing a solution w.r.t. your code would be wrong. Instead, I'm going to drop an example that's meant to help you understand how react works and how to implement what you intend.

You could always use ReactDOM, but it would be an overkill. You can instead use `event.target.value` to directly get the updated value from the `<select />` box. How you populate the `<select />` box is entirely up to you. I prefer using `Array.map()` to iterate over the data and return a set of `<option />`s.

Also note that `() => {}` is arrow function from es6. You can replace that with es5 `function() {}` anytime.

```
import React from 'react';

class SelectExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: 0
    }
    this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
  }

  updateValue(value) {
    this.setState({
      selectedValue: value
    }, () => alert(value));
  }

  render() {
    const dataSet = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    return (
      <div>
        <select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={(e) => this.updateValue(+e.target.value)}>
          <option value={0}>Default Value</option>
          {
            dataSet.map((item, idx) => <option value={item} key={idx}>{"Example " + item}</option>)
          }
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This code is not tested. So you may want to clear some errors, if any. You're going totally against React's use case by using `document.getElementById`. Please change your code to something like I have posted here.

Also read [Controlled Component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)